# Generic FV of PV Formula with equal inflation and savings rate

Tags: savings, retirement-plan, investment-income

I’m trying to arrive at a formula that allows me to determine the future value of a present savings amount (P), given the following:

Period (p): e.g., Annual (p=1), Semiannual (p=2), Quarterly (p=4), Monthly (p=12)
Years of withdrawals: y
Annual withdrawal amount: W
Annual savings growth percent: r
Periodic savings growth rate: m = (1+r)^(1/p)-1
Annual inflation percent: i

I found a formula on this forum that allows for the above, based on withdrawals at the END of the chosen period as follows:

FV = W/p*(r/m)*[(1+i)^y-(1+m)^(y*p)]/(r-i) + P*(1+m)^(y*p)

I was able to modify it to allow withdrawals at the beginning of the chosen period as follows:

FV = W/p*(1+1/m)*[(1+i)^y-(1+m)^(y*p)]/(r-i) + P*(1+m)^(y*p)

But the above formulas provide errors when i = r. I’ve been trying to arrive at a general formula that allows the inflation rate to equal the savings rate.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you link to the source of the formula you found? You'd have the same problem in the original formula, so I don;t think changing the withdrawal timing is the main problem.

Comment: If i = r, then future dollars are identical to current dollars. This is because you are assumed to be earning exactly at the rate of inflation. In this case, the present value is identical to the future value. ie: $500 received in 12 months would be the same as $500 received today.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a simple case: 3 years annual withdrawals and compounding, no inflation.

```
P = 1000
W = -120
r = 10%

P = 1000
P = (P + W) (1 + r)
P = (P + W) (1 + r)
P = (P + W) (1 + r) = 894.08
```

Same result using a formula, with `n = 3`

[image]

Now with inflation at `i = 12%` diminishing the purchasing value of `P`

```
P = 1000
P = (P + W) (1 + r)/(1 + i)
P = (P + W) (1 + r)/(1 + i)
P = (P + W) (1 + r)/(1 + i) = 600.084
```

[image]

Formula for future value adjusted for inflation is

```
FV = W (1+i)^-n (1+r) ((1+i)^n - (1+r)^n)/(i-r) + P (1+r)^n/(1+i)^n
```

For different compounding periods modify `r`, `i` and `W` accordingly, e.g. for monthly

```
r = (1 + 0.1)^(1/12) - 1
i = (1 + 0.12)^(1/12) - 1
W = -120/12 = -10
```

This assumes the withdrawal frequency follows the compounding frequency.  Alas `W` is not adjusted for inflation here.

***Continued in the light of OP's comment***

The OP wants to apply inflation to the withdrawals so that they retain their purchasing power.  So same simple 3 year model:-

```
P = 1000
W = -120
r = 0.1
i = 0.12

P = 1000;
P = (P + W (1 + i)^0) (1 + r)
P = (P + W (1 + i)^1) (1 + r)
P = (P + W (1 + i)^2) (1 + r) = 843.075
```

As a summation and formula with `n = 3`

[image]

When `ì ≠ r` the formula can be used:

```
FV = W (1+r) ((1+i)^n - (1+r)^n)/(i-r) + P (1+r)^n
```

and in the case where `i = r` a loop could be used, e.g.

```
subtotal = 0

For[k = 1, k <= n, k++,
 subtotal += W (1 + i)^(n - k) (1 + r)^k]

subtotal + P (1 + r)^n
```

> 843.075

Comment: So what happens when `r=i`? That's the original question.

Comment: @DStanley Yes, that's interesting, the `i - r` denominator in the formula results in a division by zero error, but no problem in the summation where `(1 + r)^k / (1 + i)^k` just becomes 1.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback! What I meant by inflation is that the amount taken out every year will increase by the inflation amount. In the example above, the withdrawal amounts would grow annually by Y(n) = W*(1+i)^(n-1). I'm trying to create an Excel data table with savings growth on one axis and inflation, i.e., annual withdrawal amounts on the other axis. I was able to do a workaround with correction factors when r = i, i.e., multiply r by 0.9999999 when r=i; it provides correct answers up to two significant digits. I was hoping to arrive at a formula that provides this.